# How to get session value asp.net core inside a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I am trying to get session like this

```
@HttpContext.Session.GetString("some");
```

But I am getting

*

> An object reference is required for the non-static field ......

*

Any one with ideas?

Comment: This should be a bug on MS Learn doc. I created an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/29273

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have to inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` implementation to the views and use it.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
```

Now you can access the `HttpContext` property and then `Session`

```
<p>
    @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("MySessionKey")
</p>
```

Assuming you have all the necessary setup done to enable session in the `startup` class.

In your `ConfigureServices` method,

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

and `IApplicationBuilder.UseSession` method call in the `Configure` method.

```
app.UseSession();
```

Comment: @Navigator Just to add what `@Shyju` has suggested, `IHttpContextAccessor ` would work but it may add some significant performance overhead (as reported [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/190)) and hence starting from `ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2` it is not registered by default and hence you would need to do some configuration in `Starup.cs` as suggested by `@Shyju`. An alternate solution would be to add `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` on top and then `@HttpContext.Session.GetString("some");` would work.

Comment: çox sağol (Thanks) @shyju

Comment: GetInt32 doesn't seem to be available? Need to add @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

Answer (score 10):

First enable session by adding the following 2 lines of code inside the ConfigureServices method of startup class:

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddSession();
```

In the same method add the code for creating singleton object for IHttpContextAccessor to access the session in the view.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Now inside the Configure method of startup class you will have to add .UseSession() before the .UseMvc():

```
app.UseSession();
```

The full code of Startup class is given below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession();
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseStatusCodePages();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        // Default Route
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Then go to the view and add the following 2 lines at the top:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
```

And then you can get the value from session variable in the view like:

```
@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("some")
```

I have only modified the answer from @Shyju by including the complete code.

Answer (score 3):

I know there has already been answers, but for ASP.NET Core 6 things little changed.

Again you have to add Session in services, and use it in middleware pipeline.

In Program.cs add the following

```
builder.Services.AddSession();

app.UseSession();
```

But instead of injecting HttpContextAccesor and so on, you can have direct access to Context class in view like this`

```
        Context.Session.SetInt32("sessionInt",1);
```

@Context.Session.GetInt32("userId")

Comment: This answer should mark as right one for ASP․NET Core 3.1+. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686#access-httpcontext-from-a-razor-view-in-mvc-1

Comment: @Context.Session.GetInt32("userId")